# Can't change HTML dropdown list value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I created a site: [pg.wcyat.me](https://pg.wcyat.me) ([Source code](https://gitlab.com/wcyat-me/pg.wcyat.me)), using [github.com/thdoan/pretty-dropdowns](https://github.com/thdoan/pretty-dropdowns) for dropdown lists.
I can change the value of select lists, using javascript, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('numbers').value = "false"
$dropdown.refresh()
```

then the "include numbers" list would show false.

However, if I change in the interface (changing "include numbers" from "true" (initial value) to "false" using the dropdown list), then:

```
document.getElementById('numbers').value
//returns "true"
```

if I refresh it:

```
$dropdown.refresh()
```

the "include numbers" list would show "true", as if I have never changed the option.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.wcyat.me/css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pg.wcyat.me/assets/css/input.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pg.wcyat.me/assets/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pg.wcyat.me/assets/css/prettydropdowns.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://static.wcyat.me/js/init.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <center>
                <h1 style="background-color: black; color: white; height: 150px; width: 100%; padding-top: 50px;" id="output"></h1>
                <div class="iota">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: large;" onclick="copy()" id="copy">Copy</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: large;" onclick="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = generate(); document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = 'Copy'" value="Generate">Generate</button>
                </div>
            <div>
                <h1><strong>Options</strong></h1>
                <label style="margin-left: 10px;" for="numbers">Include numbers</label>
                <label style="margin-left: 20px" for="upper">Include uppercase characters</label>
                <label style="margin-left: 20px" for="lower">Include lowercase characters</label>
                <label style="margin-left: 20px" for="special">Include special characters</label><br>
                <select id="numbers" name="numbers" onchange="change('numbers')">
                    <option value="true">true</option>
                    <option value="false">false</option> 
                </select>
                <select style="margin-left: 60px;" id="upper" name="upper" onchange="change('upper')">
                    <option value="true">true</option>
                    <option value="false">false</option> 
                </select>
                <select style="margin-left: 80px;" id="lower" name="lower" onchange="change('lower')">
                    <option value="true">true</option>
                    <option value="false">false</option> 
                </select>
                <select style="margin-left: 60px;" id="special" name="special" onchange="change('special')">
                    <option value="true">true</option>
                    <option value="false">false</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
            </center>
            </section>
        </main>
        <script src="https://pg.wcyat.me/assets/js/jquery.prettydropdowns.js"></script>
        <script src="https://pg.wcyat.me/assets/js/pg-web.js"></script>
        <script src="https://pg.wcyat.me/assets/js/copy.js"></script>
        <script src="https://pg.wcyat.me/assets/js/select.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $dropdown = $('select').prettyDropdown();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problem you are exactly facing? it's not clear

Comment: I can't change the option of a dropdown list as a user. That is, visually it is changed, but actually it's not.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with CDN versions of your plugins using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: I see the values I chose as `class="selected"` here : `<ul tabindex="0" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="menu411779999995231600" aria-activedescendant="item411779999995231600-2" aria-expanded="false" style="max-height:48px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;" class=""><li id="item411779999995231600-2" data-value="false" role="option" style="width: 87.0833px;" class="selected">false<span aria-hidden="true" class="checked"> ✓</span></li><li id="item411779999995231600-1" data-value="true" role="option" class="" style="width: 87.0833px;">true</li></ul>`

Comment: you need to change which option is `selected` not the value of a `option` or the `select`

Comment: Why use dropdown.refresh()?
This code resets the value of all drop-down menus

Comment: @Anuga document.querySelector('#numbers > [value="false"]').selected is false when "false" is selected.

Comment: @devzarghami it sets the selected option to the set select value, if I am not wrong.

Comment: This code resets the value of the menus and this is incorrect
You should only use it when you want to reset all values

Answer (score 1):

```
function selected() {
    for (let i in options.include) {
        document.getElementById(i).value = options.include[i]
    }
}

function change(v) {
    options.include[v] = !options.include[v]
}
```

Comment: if options is not just true or false this would not work, and document.getElementById(i).value must me a string.